# Can I always use std::inserter(container, container.end()) instead of std::back_inserter(container)?

Tags: c++, c++11

`std::back_inserter` only works for container with `push_back`, so it won't work for `set` and `map`

On the other hand, `std::inserter` works for all container types. So can I always use `std::inserter(container, container.end())` ?

So is the following code good for all kind of container types?

```
template <class TContainer, class TElement>
TContainer create(TElement element)
{
    TContainer container;
    auto inserter = std::inserter(container, container.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < some_number; ++i)
    {
        element = do_something(element);
        if (condition)
        {
            *inserter++ = element;
        }
    }
    return container;
}

// use like
create<std::vector<int>>(1);
create<std::set<int>>(1);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will work with the exception that standard class `std::forward_list` has no method `insert`

Comment: it don't have `push_back` either... with `push_front` I need to insert in reverse order so I think not worth it to support `forward_list` in my case