# What's the benefit of std::back_inserter over std::inserter?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator, containers

As far as I can tell, anywhere `std::back_inserter` works in an STL algorithm, you could pass an `std::inserter` constructed with `.end()` instead:

```
std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), std::back_inserter(dest_list));
std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), std::inserter(dest_list, dest_list.end()));
```

AND, unlike `back_inserter`, as far as I can tell `inserter` works for ANY STL container!! I tried it successfully for `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::map`, `std::unordered_map` before coming here surprised.

I thought that maybe it's because `push_back` could be faster for some structures than `insert(.end())`, but I'm not sure...

That doesn't seem to be the case for `std::list` (makes sense):

```
// Copying 10,000,000 element-list with std::copy. Did it twice w/ switched order just in case that matters.
Profiling complete (884.666 millis total run-time): inserter(.end())
Profiling complete (643.798 millis total run-time): back_inserter
Profiling complete (644.060 millis total run-time): back_inserter
Profiling complete (623.151 millis total run-time): inserter(.end())
```

But it does slightly for `std::vector`, though I'm not really sure why?:

```
// Copying 10,000,000 element-vector with std::copy.
Profiling complete (985.754 millis total run-time): inserter(.end())
Profiling complete (746.819 millis total run-time): back_inserter
Profiling complete (745.476 millis total run-time): back_inserter
Profiling complete (739.774 millis total run-time): inserter(.end())
```

I guess in a vector there is slightly more overhead figuring out where the iterator is and then putting an element there vs just arr[count++]. Maybe it's that?

But still, is that the main reason?

My followup question, I guess, is "Is it okay to write `std::inserter(container, container.end())` for a templated function and expect it to work for (almost) any STL container?"

---

I updated the numbers after moving to a standard compiler. Here is my compiler's details:

gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu

My build command:

```
g++ -O0 -std=c++11 algo_test.cc
```

---

I think [this question asks the second half of my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23360656/751061), namely, "Can I write a templated function that uses `std::inserter(container, container.end())` and expect it to work for almost every container?"

The answer there was "Yes, for every container except for `std::forward_list`." But based on the discussion in the comments below and in [user2746253](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2746253/user2746253)'s answer, it sounds like I should be aware that this would be slower for `std::vector` than using `std::back_inserter`...

Therefore, I might want to specialize my template for containers using `RandomAccessIterator`s to use `back_inserter` instead. Does that make sense? Thanks.

Comment: `back_inserter_iterator` calls `push_back`, so of course it doesn't work with all containers. On the other hand, `insert_iterator` calls `insert`. The speed of these operations depends on what you're trying to do. `works for ANY STL container!!` is wrong. Maybe [C++ vector's insert & push_back difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324431/c-vectors-insert-push-back-difference) will be informative.

Comment: Good question. It is interesting that inserter with the end iterator is slower than back_inserter on a vector. You didn't mention your compiler or optimization modes, however.

Comment: @remyabel: Yes, thanks, that link was helpful. They came to the same conclusion I did, which is that `insert` will be slightly slower because extra branching is required to check that the iterator is at the end.

Comment: @remyabel: Which STL containers does `inserter` not work for?

Comment: @NHDaly Containers that don't have `insert` as a public member function.

Comment: For example, `std::queue`

Comment: Oh right, good one. Thanks.

Comment: Those two have different requirements and guarantees. For example, `inserter` for a `std::vector<T>` requires that `T` is MoveAssignable, `back_inserter` does not. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b18eeb23c18b0e0)

Comment: If you are measuring performance, don't use `-O0`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: `std::queue` is not a container but a *container adaptor*; for example, it doesn't even have `begin()` and `end()`.

Comment: @T.C. I'm sorry; what is a better setting then? Should I use `-O3`?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

### Iterator types

- `std::back_inserter` returns `std::back_insert_iterator` that uses  `Container::push_back()`.
- `std::inserter` returns `std::insert_iterator` that uses  `Container::insert()`.

### std::list

For lists `std::list::push_back` is almost the same as `std::list::insert`. The only difference is that insert returns iterator to inserted element.

bits/stl_list.h

```
void push_back(const value_type& __x)
  { this->_M_insert(end(), __x); }
void _M_insert(iterator __position, const value_type& __x)
  {
    _Node* __tmp = _M_create_node(__x);
    __tmp->_M_hook(__position._M_node);
  }
```

bits/list.tcc

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc> typename list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator
list<_Tp, _Alloc>::insert(iterator __position, const value_type& __x)
  {
  _Node* __tmp = _M_create_node(__x);
  __tmp->_M_hook(__position._M_node);
  return iterator(__tmp);
  }
```

### std::vector

It looks a little different for `std::vector`. Push back checks if reallocation is needed, and if not just places value in correct place.

bits/stl_vector.h

```
void push_back(const value_type& __x)
  {
  if (this->_M_impl._M_finish != this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage)
    {
    _Alloc_traits::construct(this->_M_impl, this->_M_impl._M_finish, __x);
    ++this->_M_impl._M_finish;
    }
  else
    _M_insert_aux(end(), __x);
  }
```

But in `std::vector::insert` there are 3 additional things done and it impacts performance.
bits/vector.tcc

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc> typename vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator
vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::insert(iterator __position, const value_type& __x)
  {
  const size_type __n = __position - begin(); //(1)
  if (this->_M_impl._M_finish != this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage
  && __position == end()) //(2)
    {
    _Alloc_traits::construct(this->_M_impl, this->_M_impl._M_finish, __x);
    ++this->_M_impl._M_finish;
    }
  else
    {
    _M_insert_aux(__position, __x);
    }
  return iterator(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n); //(3)
  }
```

Comment: I like the high-level/concise explanation which boils down to `push_back()` vs `insert()` --> this answers the question without getting bogged down AND is still sufficiently technical (i.e. non hand wavy).

Comment: I don't think the three additional commands cause a big performance difference. What does make a difference though is that `_M_insert_aux` inserts at the end for `push_back` (i.e. it's just an append), but it inserts somewhere in the middle for `insert`, which causes all the following data to be pushed back.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is that `std::insert_iterator` allows you to insert at any position in the container:

```
//insert at index 2
auto it = std::inserter(v, v.begin() + 2);
*it = 4;
```

To accomplish this, std::vector must move existing elements after index 2 one place down in above example. This is `O(n)` operation unless you are inserting at the end because there is nothing else to move down. But still it needs to make relevant checks which causes `O(1)` perf penalty. For linked lists, you can insert at any place in `O(1)` time so no penalty there. The `back_inserter` always inserts at the end so no penalty there either.